# Static site that is on the same server as a Wordpress blog is being altered by the Wordpress blog's plugins

Tags: wordpress

A long while back i had to make a simple static site for a person. A while later she wanted to have a blog as well so we opted for adding a wordpress blog styled like the static site.

This all went well until she starter installing a pretty big number of plugins on the Wordpress blog, and she started noticing that the plugins were also changing things on the static site.

The static site is on the server root and Wordpress blog is in a sub-directory, /blog. I assume that this is what is causing the issue, i was not expecting it at all but thinking about it it makes sense, and i feel like a pretty big dumbdumb now...

What i need is to make sure that wordpress can't act outside of it's directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of changes occured?

Comment: One example being there being pinterest buttons all over the static site.

Comment: No way, you are seeing wordpress site I think. That is not static page. You have sample urls?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have any examples to share, when we noticed what was going on we disabled all the plugins that were acting on the static site.

To clarify, when i say static site i mean a simple html/css site.

Comment: There is no way to effect static site. I think, you are thinking it is effecting static site but actually not. It is already wordpress site, If you are using same template.